# Como posso testar webservice autenticado?

Tags: c#, web-service

Olá, tenho um serviço de autenticação já montado em c# e queria fazer qualquer teste que seja com ele. Pode ser alguma pagina webform, que retorne um positivo ou negativo, ou uma classe c# mesmo que rode por console e faça o mesmo. Já tem toda estrutura montada, é só consumir, já tenho uma senha no web.config com md5. é usando SOAP o serviço.

```
namespace Test.Services
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TestService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.este.com.br", Description = "Servico de interface com o sistema de gerenciamento eletronico de documentos")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(Description="Metodo que adiciona um arquivo a base do Test")]
    public void  AddArquivo(Autenticacao aut, Arquivo arq)
    {
        Autenticar(aut);
        ArquivoController.GetInstance().AddArquivo(arq);
    }        

    [WebMethod]
    public Arquivo GetArquivo(Autenticacao autenticacao)
    {
        return null;
    }        


    /// <summary>
    /// Método que executa a autenticação dos utilizadores do webservices
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aut">Objeto contendo a autenticação</param>
    private void Autenticar(Autenticacao aut)
    {
        if (string.Compare(aut.Usuario, Util.Util.WebConfigurations.GetValue("usuariowebservice")) != 0 || string.Compare(Util.Util.GUIDs.GetKeyMD5(aut.Senha), Util.Util.WebConfigurations.GetValue("senhawebservice")) != 0)
            throw new TestServiceException("Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Classe que do objeto de autenticação dos usuários do serviço
/// </summary>
public class Autenticacao
{
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
}
```

Como criar uma classe de teste, pra tentar autenticar com uma senha qualquer?
apenas testar.

Comment: Eu só queria chamar atenção para um ponto. `(...)já tenho uma senha no web.config com md5(...)` não sei o motivo disso, mas se é por questão de segurança isso é um esforço em vão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, para isto você pode usar o [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)
Então adicione o endereço do seu webservice, que deve ser algo do genero:
http://localhost:xxxxx/testeservice.asmx

Apenas uma dica, para webservices novos, lhe aconselho usar WCF, como no exemplo abaixo...
inicie um novo projeto utilizando WCF Service Application.
neste projeto, você terá uma interface e uma classe, chamadas respectivamente de IService e Service.
A sua interface seria algo do genero:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.este.com.br")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void AddArquivo(Autenticacao aut, Arquivo arq);

    [OperationContract]
    Arquivo GetArquivo(Autenticacao autenticacao);
}

[DataContract]
public class Autenticacao
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Senha { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Arquivo
{

}
```

E a sua classe algo do genero:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void AddArquivo(Autenticacao aut, Arquivo arq)
    {
        Autenticar(aut);
        ArquivoController.GetInstance().AddArquivo(arq);
    }

    public Arquivo GetArquivo(Autenticacao autenticacao)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private void Autenticar(Autenticacao aut)
    {
        if (string.Compare(aut.Usuario, Util.Util.WebConfigurations.GetValue("usuariowebservice")) != 0 || string.Compare(Util.Util.GUIDs.GetKeyMD5(aut.Senha), Util.Util.WebConfigurations.GetValue("senhawebservice")) != 0)
            throw new TestServiceException("Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)");
    }
}
```

Para testar, basta dá um "Play" estando com a Classe Service aberta.

Comment: pode me da um exemplo em codigo?

Comment: Amigo, o SoapUI é apenas um programa, então não precisa implementar nenhum codigo, quanto ao WCF, adicionei um exemplo na resposta.